# Return SOLR response only if date is present

Tags: solr, solrcloud

I have 10 documents in solr. Out of 10 documents, only 8 documents have a field called date. I need a query to fetch only the documents that has date present in it. I already tried with **fq=date:***  but this is returning 0 results. Any leads would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Tried something like fq=date:[* TO *]  and it seems to work !